# HTML Clear a Table and Insert Data

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

**Note: I do NOT want to touch any of the data inside of the database. I'm talking about deleting the HTML table.**

**Also, I have tried using ".html()" and ".remove()" on my table but they end up breaking the formatting and or not allowing any information to show up.**

I am going to try to explain my problem to the best of my ability with as much code as I can, so if anything is missing please let me know and I will add it.

- Right now I have an HTML page where I have a table.
- This HTML table contains several rows of MYSQL data which is fetched from a database.
- On page load the initial data is fetched and shown inside the table.
- I have several different sorting options on the top of my page that I am trying to make sort the data in the table based on things like date created, is the person paid, and are the verified. (These are just a few examples.

**I want to be able to clear the table on click of one of these sorting options and have PHP re-query the database and pull the information with the sorted condition attached.**

The query works, and the data is added to the table. HOWEVER, instead of replacing the old data and showing the sorted data, the new (sorted) data, is APPENDED to the top of the table, thus leaving the old data.

How do I fix this? I only want the new sorted data to show.

**This if statement checks to see if a drop-down menu called hasBeenSubmitted has had one if it's options clicked, and if so, it does the below based on the option selected.**

```
if(checkValue($_POST['hasBeenSubmitted'])) {
switch($_POST['hasBeenSubmitted']) {
    case 'yes':
        $query1 = "SELECT *
FROM APPLICATION_Primary
INNER JOIN Application ON Application_primary.applicationId = Application.applicationId AND     hasBeenSubmitted = 1
INNER JOIN Applicant ON Applicant.applicantId = Application.applicantId
INNER JOIN APPLICATION_Degree ON Application.applicationId = APPLICATION_Degree.applicationId
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT (
department_code
), academic_programCode, department_nameFull
FROM  AcademicProgram) AS 
ac_program ON APPLICATION_Degree.academic_program = ac_program.department_code
INNER JOIN APPLICATION_Transaction ON Application.transactionId =     APPLICATION_Transaction.transactionId
ORDER BY Applicant.applicantId ASC";



//SOMEHOW CLEAR THE TABLE HERE?


//QUERY
         $updatedapplicants = $db->query($query1);
         populateTable($updatedapplicants);
        break;
    case 'no':
        $query1 = "SELECT *
FROM APPLICATION_Primary
INNER JOIN Application ON Application_primary.applicationId = Application.applicationId AND     hasBeenSubmitted = 0
INNER JOIN Applicant ON Applicant.applicantId = Application.applicantId
INNER JOIN APPLICATION_Degree ON Application.applicationId = APPLICATION_Degree.applicationId
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT (
department_code
), academic_programCode, department_nameFull
FROM  AcademicProgram) AS 
ac_program ON APPLICATION_Degree.academic_program = ac_program.department_code
INNER JOIN APPLICATION_Transaction ON Application.transactionId =     APPLICATION_Transaction.transactionId
ORDER BY Applicant.applicantId ASC";

     //SOMEHOW CLEAR THE TABLE HERE?

         //QUERY
         $updatedapplicants = $db->query($query1);
         populateTable($updatedapplicants);
        break;
}
}
```

**Here is populateTable() which does exactly what you'd think. It takes the information received from the applicants variables and pulls the columns it needs and echo's them inside the table.**

```
function populateTable($updatedapplicants) {

foreach($updatedapplicants as $applicant) {
$color = $color == 'light'? 'dark' : 'light';
?>
<tr
    class='<?php echo $color;?>'     id='applicant_data'>
<td style="text-align: center;"><?PHP echo '<input type="checkbox"  class="processed_check"     id="applicant-' . $applicant['applicant_id'] . '" ';
if($applicant['status'] == 1){
    echo "checked";
}
echo '>';
?></td>

<td><?php echo $applicant['applicantId']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $applicant['isPayingOnline']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo ($applicant['hasBeenSubmitted'] == 1) ? 'yes' : 'no'; ?></td>

<!-- applicant info -->
<td><?php 
if($applicant['hasBeenSubmitted '] == 1) {
    $exDOB = explode("/", $applicant['date_of_birth']);
    $newDOB = $exDOB[0].$exDOB[1].$exDOB[2];
    $pdftitle = $applicant['applicationId']."_".$applicant['familyName']."_".$applicant['givenName']."_".$newDOB.".p    df";
    echo "<a href='getFile.php?FileName=" . $pdftitle . "&FileType=application' target='_blank'>" . $applicant['applicant_name'] . "</a>";
} else {
    echo $applicant['givenName']." ".$applicant['familyName'];
}
?></td>

<!-- academic info -->
<td><?php echo $applicant['academic_programCode'] . ' - ' . $applicant['department_nameFull']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $applicant['submittedDate'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $applicant['startSemester'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $applicant['startYear'] ?></td>

<td><?php echo ($applicant['isCompleted'] == 'Y') ? "yes" : "no"; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $applicant['studentType'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $applicant['academic_load'] ?></td>
<td><?php 
$email = $applicant['loginEmail'];
echo "<a href='mailto:$email'>$email</a>";
?></td>
<td><?php
if ($applicant['essayOldFileName']) {
    $exDOB = explode("/", $applicant['date_of_birth']);
    $newDOB = $exDOB[0].$exDOB[1].$exDOB[2];
    $ext = end(explode(".", $applicant['essayOldFileName']));
    $filename = "essay_".$applicant['applicantId']."_".$applicant['givenName']."_".$applicant['familyName']."_".$new    DOB.".".$ext;
    echo "<a href='getFile.php?FileName=$filename&FileType=essay' target='_blank'>Essay</a>";
}
?></td>
<td><?php
if($applicant['resumeOldFileName']) {
    $exDOB = explode("/", $applicant['date_of_birth']);
    $newDOB = $exDOB[0].$exDOB[1].$exDOB[2];
    $ext = end(explode(".", $applicant['resume_file_name']));
    $filename = "resume_".$applicant['applicant_id']."_".$applicant['given_name']."_".$applicant['family_name']."_".    $newDOB.".".$ext;
    echo "<a href='getFile.php?FileName=$filename&FileType=resume' target='_blank'>Resume</a>";
}
?></td>
</tr>

<?php }
}
```

Thank you, I appreciate all help. I am really stuck on this issue.

Comment: Have you tried using populateTable() to create the table instead of just the rows and cells? That way on populateTable() call, you can use .remove() on the old table, and then redraw it.

Comment: It may not be particularly the best solution, but I can't advise beyond that without seeing more of your code. Since you have access to .remove() and .html(), I see you're using jQuery... have you looked into [DataTables?](http://datatables.net/)

Comment: I am not the original creator of the table so I'm having a hard time understanding how to re-create the table in the same format they used. Since this isn't my own project I unfortunately can't use plug-ins and need to use the existing code I was given. I can give you any other code you'd like to see though, just name it.

Comment: Can you show me where the table itself is created?